# Gradle release build still debuggable?

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, release

According to the Gradle docs, the default value for "debuggable" a "release" buildType is false. However, whether I explicitly set it to false or not, my release build always seems to be debuggable (I can see logcat output). Am I misinterpreting this property? Can someone please explain?

Here's my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1:facebook')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':nineoldandroids')
    compile project(':SlidingMenu-master:library')
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':windowed-seek-bar')
    compile files('compile-libs/androidannotations-2.7.1.jar', 'libs/Flurry_3.2.1.jar', 'libs/google-play-services.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar', 'libs/picasso-1.1.1.jar', 'libs/crittercism_v3_0_11_sdkonly.jar', 'libs/gcm.jar', 'libs/apphance-library.jar')
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('keystores/debug.keystore')
        }

        release {
            storeFile file('keystores/release.keystore')
            storePassword "***"
            keyAlias "***"
            keyPassword "***"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src', 'normal']
                    resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                    aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                    renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                    assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Viewing logcat is not tied to whether the app is debuggable or not.

If you see the process in DDMS then your app is debuggable (unless you're looking at an emulator in which case all apps are considered debuggable).

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Build -> Generate Signed APK in Android Studio, it's using `assembleDebug` gradle task instead of `assembleRelease`. Try executing `assembleRelease` task manually and debuggable flag should be false

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that debug is not allowed, you can declare `debuggable=false` in your application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml. Don't know if it will help in your case.